# How to have a huge list? Greather than 2 GiB?

Tags: .net, memory-management

In .Net framework **2 GiB** is the highest memory that you can allocate for an object. This fact is **independent** from platform (**x64** or x86 or ...).
I need to have a huge list with more than 2^30 Complex Numbers (each one is 16 bytes).

Note:

> As with 32-bit Windows operating systems, there is a 2GB limit on the
>   size of an object you can create while running a 64-bit managed
>   application on a 64-bit Windows operating system.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: You need an object that will take up over 17.18 GB of RAM? Unless you've got some great servers you're probably going to need to think of a different way of doing this.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: @Ben why? I've got more than that in my desktop...

Comment: I hope your numbers are a Value Type (a struct) instead of a Reference type (a class)... Otherwise your memory use will baloon.

Comment: @LuKe H: I was wrote my HugeArray that implemented like that article but the OutOfMemory exception was thrown.

Comment: @Ben: I have 16 GiB of RAM. but i cant allocate more than 2 GiB in one object!!

Comment: @salman Are you compiling to 64 bits? Visual Studio 2010 defaults to x86 mode. Try checking `Environment.Is64BitProcess`

Comment: @xanatos: Yes. I'm sure that is's compiling and running in x64

Comment: @salman Then it's strange you had an out-of-memory using the BigArray of the example. Unless your number type is a class. Then the memory use will baloon VERY much (around 2x)

Comment: @xanatos: See it -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28VS.80%29.aspx "As with 32-bit Windows operating systems, there is a 2GB limit on the size of an object you can create while running a 64-bit managed application on a 64-bit Windows operating system."
I need about 8 GiB :D

Comment: @salman I do know perfectly that, but the source given by LukeH is done exactly for this reason.

Comment: @xanatos,LuKe H: Thanks. I was wrong because of Visual Studio foolishness :D. Solution platform may be different in its projects. My HugeArray was in other project that was compiling in x86 mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd implement a wrapper class that uses multiple arrays internally.

Similar to the following:

```
void Main()
{
    long count=3*1024*1024;
    var arr=new LargeArray<Complex>(count,12);
    for(long i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
      arr[i]=new Complex(i,-i);
    }
    for(long i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i].R!=i)
        throw new Exception("Fail"+i+" "+arr[i].R);
    }
}

struct Complex
{
  public double R,I;

  public Complex(double r,double i)
    {
      R=r;
      I=i;
    }
}


class LargeArray<T>
{
  private readonly int partBits;  
  private readonly long size;

  private T[][] data;

  public T this[long index]
  {
    get
    {
      if((ulong)index>=(ulong)size)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
      int part=(int)(index>>partBits);
      int subIndex=(int)(index&((1<<partBits)-1));
      return data[part][subIndex];
    }
    set
    {
      if((ulong)index>=(ulong)size)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      int part=(int)(index>>partBits);
      int subIndex=((int)index&((1<<partBits)-1));
      data[part][subIndex]=value;
    }
  }

  public LargeArray(long size,int partBits)
  {
    this.size=size;
    this.partBits=partBits;
    int partSize=1<<partBits;
    int partCount=(int)(((size-1)>>partBits)+1);
    data=new T[partCount][];
    for(int i=0;i<partCount;i++)
      data[i]=new T[partSize];
  }
}
```

If you use a 64 bit process this works beyond 2GB. I tried it with 5GB and apart from swapping my comp to a halt it worked.

Comment: Small correction: the last block could be smaller (9 elements in "blocks" of 4: 4, 4, 1)

Comment: @salman after fixing a few minor issues this code works fine beyond 2GB. In my tests it dealt fine is allocating 5 GB of memory. Of course I ran it as a 64 bit process. So I don't see what your issue is. But since you are sure that your process is 64 bit, that can't be your issue either. So the only thing I can think of is that you used a `Complex` class not a `Complex` struct.

Comment: @xanatos I know. But that's a minor optimization issue. If you allocate 5GB of memory you won't care about 1MB more or less.

Comment: By changing it then you can remove the checks for IndexOutOfRangeException and use directly the one of array and this could speed up a little the code. And then you'll have blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx :-) :-) only with configurable blocksize

Answer (score 2):

Then you'll need to encapsulate that in some other way - create your own collection which *can* handle enough data, and will probably use `long` instead of `int` for the index values, etc, by delegating to smaller collections internally. I suspect it won't be a lot of fun, but I can't see you've got many other options.

Fundamentally, anything that's backed by a single array is going to run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Make it jagged instead; a `Complex[][]` for example. It can be broadly-rectangular jagged, if you need, simply by always using the same size for the inner arrays.

Another option; use a linked-list of large-lists; this has the advantage of being easier to extend.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.5 it appears that arrays can actually be larger 2 GB. With a hard limit on the number of elements, rather than in size. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Talks about the new flag and the new limitations on arrays.